Is there an easy way to separate out model coefficient values into different variables?
I am looking to simplify the following:
> model$coefficients

(Intercept)          x1          x2           c 
-1.51730659  0.28487690  0.10034603  0.08629699 

  b0_i = model$coefficients[1]
  b1_x1 = model$coefficients[2]
  b2_x2 = model$coefficients[3]
  b3_c = model$coefficients[4]

It takes forever to ensure that a complex formula that uses many coefficients and refers to them by index is correct, so I want to assign each of them to a named variable.
I have tried to use lapply() and assign() using a vector of variable names:
> b_vars = c("b0_i", "b1_x1", "b2_x2", "b3_c")
> lapply(seq_along(b_vars), function(i) {assign(b_vars[i], model$coefficients[i])})

[[1]]
(Intercept) 
  -1.517307 

[[2]]
  fdr_mom 
0.2848769 

[[3]]
 fdr_dad 
0.100346 

[[4]]
      dr34 
0.08629699 

Desired output:
> b0_i
-1.51730659

> b1_x1 
0.28487690  

> b2_x2 
0.10034603

> b3_c 
0.08629699


Perhaps, broom::tidy(model) will produce what you are after.

I solved my issue using a for() loop:
b_vars = c("b0_i", "b1_x1", "b2_x2", "b3_c")

for(i in 1:length(b_vars)) {
  
  assign(b_vars[i], model$coefficients[i])
  
}


Try this.
> fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars)
> coefs <- fit$coefficients
> coef_lst <- coefs |> setNames(
+   paste0('b', seq_along(coefs) - 1, '_', sub('\\(Intercept\\)', 'i', names(coefs)))
+ ) |> as.list()
> coef_lst
$b0_i
[1] 12.30337

$b1_cyl
[1] -0.1114405

$b2_disp
[1] 0.01333524

$b3_hp
[1] -0.02148212

$b4_drat
[1] 0.787111

$b5_wt
[1] -3.715304

$b6_qsec
[1] 0.8210407

$b7_vs
[1] 0.3177628

$b8_am
[1] 2.520227

$b9_gear
[1] 0.655413

$b10_carb
[1] -0.1994193

If you really want the variables in the environment, pipe in another coef_lst |> list2env(), but it bloats the workspace and is therefore not recommended. Better work with the list, e.g. coef_lst$b0_i.
